# Using Pandas to merge similar data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How do I merge similar data such as "recommendation" into one value?

```
df['Why you choose us'].str.lower().value_counts()

location                           35
recommendation                     23
recommedation                       8
confort                             7
availability                        4
reconmmendation                     3
facilities                          3
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a way of determining if the words are similar, or are you asking for an algorithm to determine word similarity?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @Craig I'm asking for an algorithm to merge entry names (strings) that are similar so that only one number represents, for example, all entries that resemble the word "recommendation" would be counted together as a unique number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print(df)

```
            reason  count
0         location     35
1   recommendation     23
2    recommedation      8
3          confort      7
4     availability      4
5  reconmmendation      3
6       facilities      3
```

`.groupby()`, partial string.`.transform()` while finding the `sum`

```
df['groupcount']=df.groupby(df.reason.str[0:4])['count'].transform('sum')



          reason  count  groupcount
0         location     35          35
1   recommendation     23          34
2    recommedation      8          34
3          confort      7           7
4     availability      4           4
5  reconmmendation      3          34
6       facilities      3           3
```

If needed to see string and partial string side by side. Try

```
df=df.assign(groupname=df.reason.str[0:4])
df['groupcount']=df.groupby(df.reason.str[0:4])['count'].transform('sum')
print(df)


      reason  count groupname  groupcount
0         location     35      loca          35
1   recommendation     23      reco          34
2    recommedation      8      reco          34
3          confort      7      conf           7
4     availability      4      avai           4
5  reconmmendation      3      reco          34
6       facilities      3      faci           3
```

Incase you have multiple items in a row like you have in the csv; then

```
#Read csv
df=pd.read_csv(r'path')
#Create another column which is a list of values 'Why you choose us' in each row
df['Why you choose us']=(df['Why you choose us'].str.lower().fillna('no comment given')).str.split(',')
#Explode group to ensure each unique reason is int its own row but with all the otehr attrutes intact
df=df.explode('Why you choose us')
#remove any white spaces before values in the column group and value_counts
df['Why you choose us'].str.strip().value_counts()
print(df['Why you choose us'].str.strip().value_counts())

location            48
no comment given    34
recommendation      25
confort              8
facilities           8
recommedation        8
price                7
availability         6
reputation           5
reconmmendation      3
internet             3
ac                   3
breakfast            3
tranquility          2
cleanliness          2
aveilable            1
costumer service     1
pool                 1
comfort              1
search engine        1
Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ok, but how does it found similar words?

Comment: Finds similar words by slicing the first 4 characters in the column I have called reason. This is the phrase df.reason.str[0:4]

Comment: Ok, so it is basicaly proposal for calculating word similarity - words are similar when the first 4 characters are the same.

Comment: In this case, slicing 4 characters of string gives me the required sub-string to uniquely classify. See my edits

Comment: does this help?

Comment: @wwnde What this snippet

 df['groupcount']=df.groupby(df.reason.str[0:4])['count'].transform('sum') does would be a solution, however, it does not work when I run it. Maybe it has something to do with the way my data is organized? I attached a snapshot of the CSV file.

Comment: Used your csv input to make edits.I left initial solution just incase

Comment: @wwnde If I use my CSV file I get "KeyError: 'Column not found: Count'" I see that "Count" is created here: 'Count':[35,23,8,44,63,2,8,12,9]} how do I use your snippet using just the CSV file?

Comment: @wwnde for sure! I definitely appreciate your help. It's giving me perspective. I just haven't been able to resolve it yet. I would like to attach the CSV file (it's small) but I don't see a way to do it here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @wwnde the column list of numbers posted with my question is coming from value_counts(). This is in reference to "Count is your Guests." In other words, those numbers are not literally listed on the CSV file.

Comment: Can help further,  what column do you value_counts? If you wanted,  print(df).head(15).copy paste in the question and format it. Can pick it of and use

Comment: @wwnde I created a shared link on Google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IlKGKT0O3l1uiF9PRflGPFAPp0KmPCvP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can look into it in a couple of hours if someone won't have

Comment: What column do I value count to get the numbers which you had posted earlier?

Comment: @wwnde it is column "Why you choose us"
----------------code below----------------------------
path = 'data/demographics_spreadsheet.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['Why you choose us'].str.lower().value_counts()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217878/discussion-between-wwnde-and-coder3).

Comment: @coder 3, can you please accept the answer if it is working. See my edits.

Comment: @wwnde Let us continue in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217878/discussion-between-wwnde-and-coder3